# Radio Buttons Not Staying True To Value

Tags: jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to input data into my database and none of the radio buttons are sticking. No matter what I change them to, they stay the same. They initially go in just fine(Whatever the first button is, successfully appears).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#loadingstart').hide();
    });

    function walle() {
        $('#loadingstart').show();
        var product_id_array = $('#product_id_array').val();
        var position = $('#position').val();

        var URL = "./includes/user-course-settings.php"; /////post.php will be equal the variable "comment"

        $.post(URL,
            {
                walle: "post",
                username1: username,
                position1: position,
                navpos1: navpos
            },
            function (data) {//parameter wall will be equal "post", name1 will be equal to the var "name" and comment1 will be equal to the var "comment"
                $("#startOver").prepend(data).show();// the result will be placed above the the #result div
                $('#loadingstart').hide();
            });
    }
</script>
```

I don't think there is anything specifically wrong with the MYSQLI as it does go in initially to the database. The problem is, no matter what I select the values retain the first choice within the grouped radio buttons.

```
 <div id="form">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" id="product_id_array" value="'.$product_id_array.'" />
            <div class="separateFormInput">
                <div class="radioFormQuestion">position</div>
                <div class="leftyRadio">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="position" name="position" value="left" checked="checked" />left</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="position" value="center">center</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="position" value="right">right</li>
                </div>

                <br />
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="separateFormInput">
                <div class="radioFormQuestion">Nav Position?</div>
                <div class="leftyRadio">

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="navpos" value="Left" checked="checked" />Left</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="navpos" value="Center">Center</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="navpos" value="Right">Right</li>
                </div>

                <br />
                <hr>
            </div>
            <!--submit form here-->            
                       <div class="submit" id="textRight">
                           <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:walle();" />
                           <img src="https://www.mysite.com/images/loading.gif" alt="" width="15" height="15" id="loadingstart" />

                       </div>
            <div id="startOver" style="clear: both; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not valid to add any html element to a page that has an id that is the same as another element.

The three radio buttons all with the id of position is not valid html.

So doing this

```
$('#position').val();
```

will never find any more than one element because ids should be unique

Remove the id, and get which one is selected via this jquery method

```
$('input[name=position]:checked').val();
```

i.e. get the value of the checked radio button. They all always have a value checked or not

or use a class

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Ojay ....should I do anything with the product-id_array? or leave that as is? is there a ; at the end of val() like I had before? Sorry for the basic questions

Comment: Also I'm getting a position is not defined error. `navpos1:navpos` there I would presume.

Comment: as far as I can tell you only have one element on the page with the id product_id_array, a hidden field. So what you are doing is fine. And yes sorry for the minor typo, semicolon required (edited)

Comment: Sorry I cut it down so its easier to read and get an ansewr...I'm not sure why I would be getting that on that particular one. It is no different than the others. I'm going to add it above. Can you take a look at it?

Also, how should I treat the other variables? The way I did before?

Comment: did you just add html or was there some js as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35324/discussion-between-chris-and-ojay)